# Can't solve: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a code to scrap numbers from HTML by finding the span tags and the numbers within them.

I keep getting the error "expected string or buffer".

I've read some solution while doing my search through different question, but when I try `" ''.join(some_list)"` i'm getting another error:

> "sequence item 0: expected string, Tag found"

Tried to search for that one, saw some solutions like using `.get` instead of `re.findall`, but the error keep to appear.

The code:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *
url = raw_input('Enter the URL:')
stri = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(stri)

#retrieve of the span tags

spans = ''.join(soup('span'))
numlist = list()
for tag in spans:
    num = int(re.findall('[0-9]+', tag))
    numlist.append(num)
print(numlist)
```

I saw several solutions for those type of errors, but can't seem to solve it.

What am I missing?

I added the tag.text, and the error has changed to another one, now i'm getting:
"Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed"

I looked at different posts but couldn't solve it, so I ran the code line by line to see where's the problem is, and I found that it appears when i'm running the fourth sentence in the original code:

```
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

Please help?

Comment: The first step of debugging an error message, is to find the line number. You are missing the line number.

Comment: Python didn't just say "expected string or buffer" - it wrote a stack trace showing the line that has the problem. Can you post that stack trace so we can see it? Otherwise, we have to guess where the problem is.

Comment: Debugging tip: `print` is your friend. I added `print 'badness', type(soup('span')[0])` to your code and got `badness <class 'BeautifulSoup.Tag'>`. That's not something that can be joined.

Answer (score 1):

`tag` is a `Tag` object, which contains lots of information, not just a string. If you want the text inside the tag without any markup, use `tag.text`, e.g.:

```
spans = ''.join(tag.text for tag in soup('span'))
# now `for tag in spans:` makes no sense because spans is a string
```

or

```
spans = soup('span')
for tag in spans:
    num = len(re.findall('[0-9]+', tag.text))  # note len, not int
```

Comment: The type cast to integer won't work as `re.findall` returns a list

Comment: @MosesKoledoye thanks, I copy pasted without seeing the `int`.

Comment: @AlexHall Thanks, so i've changed the code and got a different error, I added the details to my first error question.

Comment: @DorZluf that's not how it works, it's one problem per question.